# trying to add image upload to my forum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, image-uploading

```
#post_content
  %h1= @post.title
  %p= @post.content
  = image_tag @post.image.url(:medium)


#comments
  %h2
    = @post.comments.count
    Comments
  = render @post.comments

  %h3 Reply to thread
  = render "comments/form"


%br/
%hr/
%br/

= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "button"
= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want tp do this?"}, class: "button"
```

I am trying to add image upload to my forum. I can upload an image and post but once I try to view it this happens (view images). I'm stuck I need help.[post view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLQVw.png) 
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnTL6.png)

Comment: please, provide your code instead of screenshot.

Comment: im trying but it does not let me

Comment: just copy code, paste instead of link and use markdown.

Comment: Need to see your controller as well, ideally your entire code base. If you could post a link to the github repo even better

Comment: https://github.com/julianmng/forum-guildforum

Comment: Your github repo doesn't include any of the image upload code.  Please commit, push, and merge your changes for image uploading so that the github project reflects your question.

Comment: it should have it now

Comment: No dice.  If you go to the repo and look at the code there, you'll see that those changes haven't been merged.  After you commit and push, you have to make sure to merge the changes.

Comment: ok it should be there now. sorry about that

Comment: I found the problem and fixed it.

Comment: you should tell how you solved the problem, so that you can help others.